# Mathematics in Cheder

Tags: history, chinuch-education, mathematics

I recall reading that their is a pesak/teshuvah/report by a major posek, perhaps an early "later" Acharon, (Rabbi Akiva Eiger zt"l) which noted that at least elementary arithmatic or mathematics was traditionally taught in cheder. I did not make note of the makor, however. Is anyone able to provide the source?

Comment: I believe there is a Teshuva given by Rabbi Masliah Mazuz HY"D that permits learning math in a synagogue. This probably doesn't help you though.

Comment: I would still like the makor :)

Comment: Legacy of Leaders Vol. II written by Yehuda Azulai (section about Rabbi Masliah Mazuz). I don't believe it is published in his Seforim.

Comment: Question... how can you teach gematria without basic arithmatic?

Comment: @avi I don't think that's the question. Because if you want to learn Gimtarya, all you have to do is learn some math WHILE you are teaching Gimtarya. Any secular studies that are included in the Torah are certainly permitted to learn in order to understand the Torah.

Comment: @HachamGabriel I meant that I have a question. Unless you practice your math skills, Gematria is going to be lacking. (you need to notice easily when its off by one, or an atbash etc.)

Comment: @avi maybe you should make another question?

Comment: @Yirmeyahu I looked this Yabia Omer up today, not saying that I read the entire responsa but I couldn't find any reference to any major poyskim

Comment: It's a question to Yirmeyahu, not a general question :)

Comment: @avi oh. Well then I hope you get your answer soon.

Comment: @Avi I'm not sure that teaching gematria is a major part of the traditional cheder education.

Comment: Is the history of the study of mathematics by Jews on topic?

Answer (score 10):

[Sefer Sheeris HaNachala](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20471&st=&pgnum=16&hilite=) mentions in the name of the Sefer HaItim that Rav Hai Gaon said that it is permitted to teach children Arabic and mathematics in order to assist them in learning Torah.

Comment: And R' Ovadya Yosef shlita has a responsum to the rabbinate of Argentina, in which the only way their Jewish educational system may work would involve teaching math and Spanish in the beis medrish, where he references this allowance of R' Hai Gaon.

Comment: Very nice sources

Comment: @Yirmeyahu While a great source for the general concept, are you looking for Cheder (the european mode of teaching) specifically, or to young children in general?

Comment: Yes, it would have been a European posek speaking about it being part of the standard curriculum.

Comment: @Shalom do you have that source from Yabia Omer or Yechave Daat?

Comment: @HachamGabriel, Yabia Omer 7: Orach Chaim 21.

Comment: IIRC this is a misrepresentation of R. Hai who says nothing about the mathematics being in order to learn Torah.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure these quotes exactly answer your question, however they do show some of the major times when math was taught and introduced into Jewish schools. The last one seems particularly on topic.

[It was published in 1906, and reads: "On the 31st March 1805 members of the High German Jewish community in Altona formed an association with the purpose of establishing a school for Jewish boys, with lessons in religion, Hebrew, arithmetic and writing.](http://www1.uni-hamburg.de/rz3a035//breitestr.html)

[The Jews established elementary schools where boys from about 6 to 13 years of age probably learned rudimentary mathematics and certainly learned reading and writing.](http://history-world.org/history_of_education.htm)

[The subjects of instruction were in the first place the religious literature, the Bible and the Talmud. But the studies were so arranged that by the nature of the talmudic discussions they embraced all known sciences: natural history, anatomy, medicine, geometry, astronomy and foreign languages.](http://books.google.com/books?id=s18MAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA116&lpg=PA116&dq=math%20Jews%20middle%20ages%20school%20rabbi&source=bl&ots=MabJx2T0LC&sig=Vclmgw6qCNxtVL7tN1b5cE-k2NQ&hl=en&sa=X&ei=x1IDT6S4LaHy0gHw9_DVBA&ved=0CC4Q6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=math%20Jews%20middle%20ages%20school%20rabbi&f=false)

[Joseph Ibn Aknin (12th century)states in his will that the curriculum should include math amongst other secular subjects.](http://books.google.com/books?id=qwlSCIpFV5kC&pg=PA7&lpg=PA7&dq=who%20added%20math%20to%20the%20jewish%20curriculum%20europe%20middle%20ages&source=bl&ots=j90wnBgco9&sig=UWQMpBemEqqpzR2OOu52-Xi0ado&hl=en&sa=X&ei=sFgDT8ryGOLs0gHbge2KCA&ved=0CCIQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=who%20added%20math%20to%20the%20jewish%20curriculum%20europe%20middle%20ages&f=false)

Answer (score 2):

Yaskil Avdi (vol. 1 Orah Haim siman 7) permits it (he was asked by Rabbi Masliah Mazuz). As well as Sis Eliezer (vol. 9 siman 15). See the [aforementioned](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/12651) Yabia Omer 7:21.

I found in Yalkut Yosef vol. 2 pg. 255

> אין לערוך הרצאות של חול בבית הכנסת, וכל שכן לערוך שם קונצרטים וכיוצא בזה. אלא אם כן ההרצאה כוללת גם דברי חיזוק ועידוד לשמירת התורה והמצוות (כגון עריכת ''סמינרים'' לקרב רחוקים לצור מחצבתם).‏

He prohibits lectures about non-Torah things in a Shul except for Kiruv and Hizuk.